# How to concatenate a string on elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

How to concatenate a string on elastic search.
for eg: here dasboradList.views has appended to new fields.

```
       {
       "_index": "haysbisuitedev",
       "_type": "dasboardconfig",
       "_id": "35",
       "_version": 3,
       "found": true,
       "_source": {
          "userId": 35,
          "defaultDashBoard": "testsgare",
          "dasboradList": "[{\"Ids\":2,\"views\":[{\"name\":\"test\",\"defaultView\":true,\"layout\":{\"templateType\":\"1\",\"backgroundColor\":\"#DBE3F5\",\"lets\":[{\"id\":\"let_23663\",\"type\":\"\",\"rowNo\":\"0\",\"columnNo\":\"0\",\"colspan\":\"1\",\"rowspan\":\"1\",\"title\":\"\",\"dashlet\":\"\",\"bgColor\":\"\",\"width\":\"32%\",\"height\":\"27%\",\"name\":null,\"catalogId\":\"0\",\"dashletId\":\"0\",\"param\":{\"misID\":null,\"name\":null,\"graphType\":null},\"widget\":{\"headline1\":\"\",\"headline2\":\"\",\"percentage\":\"0\",\"enableWidget\":false,\"hoverOnDashelt\":false,\"chartType\":\"\",\"head1Color\":\"\",\"head2Color\":\"\",\"percentageColor\":\"\"},\"clipHeadline\":false}],\"shared\":false},\"background\":\"#6FAA87\",\"share\":null,\"comments\":null,\"shareable\":false,\"userId\":0},{\"name\":\"check\",\"defaultView\":false,\"layout\":{\"templateType\":\"1\",\"backgroundColor\":\"#DBE3F5\",\"lets\":[{\"id\":\"let_54316\",\"type\":\"\",\"rowNo\":\"0\",\"columnNo\":\"0\",\"colspan\":\"1\",\"rowspan\":\"1\",\"title\":\"\",\"dashlet\":\"\",\"bgColor\":\"\",\"width\":\"32%\",\"height\":\"27%\",\"name\":null,\"catalogId\":\"0\",\"dashletId\":\"0\",\"param\":{\"misID\":null,\"name\":null,\"graphType\":null},\"widget\":{\"headline1\":\"\",\"headline2\":\"\",\"percentage\":\"0\",\"enableWidget\":false,\"hoverOnDashelt\":false,\"chartType\":\"\",\"head1Color\":\"\",\"head2Color\":\"\",\"percentageColor\":\"\"},\"clipHeadline\":false}],\"shared\":false},\"background\":null,\"share\":null,\"comments\":null,\"shareable\":false,\"userId\":0}]}]"
       }
    },
{
       "_index": "haysbisuitedev",
       "_type": "dasboardconfig",
       "_id": "30",
       "_version": 3,
       "found": true,
       "_source": {
          "userId": 35,
          "defaultDashBoard": "testsgare",
          "dasboradList": "[{\"Ids\":2,\"views\":[{\"name\":\"test\",\"defaultView\":true,\"layout\":{\"templateType\":\"1\",\"backgroundColor\":\"#DBE3F5\",\"lets\":[{\"id\":\"let_23663\",\"type\":\"\",\"rowNo\":\"0\",\"columnNo\":\"0\",\"colspan\":\"1\",\"rowspan\":\"1\",\"title\":\"\",\"dashlet\":\"\",\"bgColor\":\"\",\"width\":\"32%\",\"height\":\"27%\",\"name\":null,\"catalogId\":\"0\",\"dashletId\":\"0\",\"param\":{\"misID\":null,\"name\":null,\"graphType\":null},\"widget\":{\"headline1\":\"\",\"headline2\":\"\",\"percentage\":\"0\",\"enableWidget\":false,\"hoverOnDashelt\":false,\"chartType\":\"\",\"head1Color\":\"\",\"head2Color\":\"\",\"percentageColor\":\"\"},\"clipHeadline\":false}],\"shared\":false},\"background\":\"#6FAA87\",\"share\":null,\"comments\":null,\"shareable\":false,\"userId\":0},{\"name\":\"check\",\"defaultView\":false,\"layout\":{\"templateType\":\"1\",\"backgroundColor\":\"#DBE3F5\",\"lets\":[{\"id\":\"let_54316\",\"type\":\"\",\"rowNo\":\"0\",\"columnNo\":\"0\",\"colspan\":\"1\",\"rowspan\":\"1\",\"title\":\"\",\"dashlet\":\"\",\"bgColor\":\"\",\"width\":\"32%\",\"height\":\"27%\",\"name\":null,\"catalogId\":\"0\",\"dashletId\":\"0\",\"param\":{\"misID\":null,\"name\":null,\"graphType\":null},\"widget\":{\"headline1\":\"\",\"headline2\":\"\",\"percentage\":\"0\",\"enableWidget\":false,\"hoverOnDashelt\":false,\"chartType\":\"\",\"head1Color\":\"\",\"head2Color\":\"\",\"percentageColor\":\"\"},\"clipHeadline\":false}],\"shared\":false},\"background\":null,\"share\":null,\"comments\":null,\"shareable\":false,\"userId\":0}]}]"
       }
    }
```

Above code specifies Elastic search index.
we want to append new field in a dasboradList.dasboradList has string type.

Needed json structure is..

```
{
           "_index": "haysbisuitedev",
           "_type": "dasboardconfig",
           "_id": "35",
           "_version": 3,
           "found": true,
           "_source": {
              "userId": 35,
              "defaultDashBoard": "testsgare",
              "dasboradList": "[{\"Ids\":2,\"views\":[{\"name\":\"test\",`\"id\":\"name+"_"+userId\",\"createdDate\":\"01-01-2016\",\"expirydays\":\"10\"`,\"defaultView\":true,\"layout\":{\"templateType\":\"1\",\"backgroundColor\":\"#DBE3F5\",\"lets\":[{\"id\":\"let_23663\",\"type\":\"\",\"rowNo\":\"0\",\"columnNo\":\"0\",\"colspan\":\"1\",\"rowspan\":\"1\",\"title\":\"\",\"dashlet\":\"\",\"bgColor\":\"\",\"width\":\"32%\",\"height\":\"27%\",\"name\":null,\"catalogId\":\"0\",\"dashletId\":\"0\",\"param\":{\"misID\":null,\"name\":null,\"graphType\":null},\"widget\":{\"headline1\":\"\",\"headline2\":\"\",\"percentage\":\"0\",\"enableWidget\":false,\"hoverOnDashelt\":false,\"chartType\":\"\",\"head1Color\":\"\",\"head2Color\":\"\",\"percentageColor\":\"\"},\"clipHeadline\":false}],\"shared\":false},\"background\":\"#6FAA87\",\"share\":null,\"comments\":null,\"shareable\":false,\"userId\":0},{\"name\":\"check\",\"defaultView\":false,\"layout\":{\"templateType\":\"1\",\"backgroundColor\":\"#DBE3F5\",\"lets\":[{\"id\":\"let_54316\",\"type\":\"\",\"rowNo\":\"0\",\"columnNo\":\"0\",\"colspan\":\"1\",\"rowspan\":\"1\",\"title\":\"\",\"dashlet\":\"\",\"bgColor\":\"\",\"width\":\"32%\",\"height\":\"27%\",\"name\":null,\"catalogId\":\"0\",\"dashletId\":\"0\",\"param\":{\"misID\":null,\"name\":null,\"graphType\":null},\"widget\":{\"headline1\":\"\",\"headline2\":\"\",\"percentage\":\"0\",\"enableWidget\":false,\"hoverOnDashelt\":false,\"chartType\":\"\",\"head1Color\":\"\",\"head2Color\":\"\",\"percentageColor\":\"\"},\"clipHeadline\":false}],\"shared\":false},\"background\":null,\"share\":null,\"comments\":null,\"shareable\":false,\"userId\":0}]}]"
           }
        },
    {
           "_index": "haysbisuitedev",
           "_type": "dasboardconfig",
           "_id": "30",
           "_version": 3,
           "found": true,
           "_source": {
              "userId": 35,
              "defaultDashBoard": "testsgare",
              "dasboradList": "[{\"Ids\":2,\"views\":[{\"name\":\"test\",`\"id\":\"name+"_"+userId\",\"createdDate\":\"01-01-2016\",\"expirydays\":\"10\"`,\"defaultView\":true,\"layout\":{\"templateType\":\"1\",\"backgroundColor\":\"#DBE3F5\",\"lets\":[{\"id\":\"let_23663\",\"type\":\"\",\"rowNo\":\"0\",\"columnNo\":\"0\",\"colspan\":\"1\",\"rowspan\":\"1\",\"title\":\"\",\"dashlet\":\"\",\"bgColor\":\"\",\"width\":\"32%\",\"height\":\"27%\",\"name\":null,\"catalogId\":\"0\",\"dashletId\":\"0\",\"param\":{\"misID\":null,\"name\":null,\"graphType\":null},\"widget\":{\"headline1\":\"\",\"headline2\":\"\",\"percentage\":\"0\",\"enableWidget\":false,\"hoverOnDashelt\":false,\"chartType\":\"\",\"head1Color\":\"\",\"head2Color\":\"\",\"percentageColor\":\"\"},\"clipHeadline\":false}],\"shared\":false},\"background\":\"#6FAA87\",\"share\":null,\"comments\":null,\"shareable\":false,\"userId\":0},{\"name\":\"check\",\"defaultView\":false,\"layout\":{\"templateType\":\"1\",\"backgroundColor\":\"#DBE3F5\",\"lets\":[{\"id\":\"let_54316\",\"type\":\"\",\"rowNo\":\"0\",\"columnNo\":\"0\",\"colspan\":\"1\",\"rowspan\":\"1\",\"title\":\"\",\"dashlet\":\"\",\"bgColor\":\"\",\"width\":\"32%\",\"height\":\"27%\",\"name\":null,\"catalogId\":\"0\",\"dashletId\":\"0\",\"param\":{\"misID\":null,\"name\":null,\"graphType\":null},\"widget\":{\"headline1\":\"\",\"headline2\":\"\",\"percentage\":\"0\",\"enableWidget\":false,\"hoverOnDashelt\":false,\"chartType\":\"\",\"head1Color\":\"\",\"head2Color\":\"\",\"percentageColor\":\"\"},\"clipHeadline\":false}],\"shared\":false},\"background\":null,\"share\":null,\"comments\":null,\"shareable\":false,\"userId\":0}]}]"
           }
        }
```

Comment: your question is not clear.  Can you provide an example of what you're trying to do and what you've tried.

Comment: Jhilden please help me.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @jhilden said , we can indeed update an specific field in a ES document. But you need to enable scripting first.

Directly from the documentation  :

```
#Index a document
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/type1/1 -d '{
    "counter" : 1,
    "tags" : ["red"]
}'



#Increase the count using inline scripting
    curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/type1/1/_update' -d '{
        "script" : {
            "inline": "ctx._source.counter += count",
            "params" : {
                "count" : 4
            }
        }
    }'
#Add a new field
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/type1/1/_update' -d '{
    "script" : "ctx._source.name_of_new_field = \"value_of_new_field\""
}'
```

You can also `update by query` in case that you don't know the id of the document or if you want to do a `bulk update`.

```
POST /twitter/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.likes++"
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "user": "kimchy"
    }
  }
}
```

More details of both concepts:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-update.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-update-by-query.html

More information about inline scripting :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/modules-scripting.html

Comment: @jhilden Mee too. I had to check the documentation before answering because usually I do what you said

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you want to **UPDATE** a record in ElasticSearch.  There is no way in ES to do a partial update.  What I mean is, there is no equivalent to this:

```
UPDATE tbl1
SET col1 = 'I am updating only 1 column'
WHERE id = 123
```

In ElasticSaerch we update a record by:

1. `GET` the record you are looking for
2. update the record
3. `POST` the **FULL**, updated, record back to ElasticSearch specifying the existing _id field.

This will overwrite the old record, something you can verify by looking at the `_version` property.

Comment: According to the documentation , you can update an specific field using scripting https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-update.html